# Preciso de ajuda em um crawler em python

Tags: python, scrapy

```
from scrapy.spiders import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from crawler.items import crawlerlistItem

class MySpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "epoca"
    allowed_domains = ["epocacosmeticos.com.br"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.epocacosmeticos.com.br/maquiagem"]

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        titles = hxs.xpath("//span[@class='pl']")
        items = []
        for titles in titles:
            item = crawlerlistItem()
            item["title"] = titles.select("a/text()").extract()
            item["link"] = titles.select("a/@href").extract()
            items.append(item)
        return items
```

Tenho essa spider, mas queria coseguir pegar todas as urls da epocacosmeticos.com.br com nome do produto, title e url sem que as informações fossem duplicadas, alguem pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 4):

Se o problema é só o facto de no fim haver informação duplicada dentro do teu `items` podes verificar se já existe antes de fazeres o append:

```
...
item["title"] = titles.select("a/text()").extract()
item["link"] = titles.select("a/@href").extract()
if item not in items:
    items.append(item)
```

Para prevenção de duplicados em uma coleção em primeira analise eu ia sugerir usar um `set()`, mas visto que `item` é um dicionário ([é mutável](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13264511/typeerror-unhashable-type-dict)) mais vale fazer o que pus em cima para não andar com muitas voltas.

Answer (score 1):

A solução proposta pelo Miguel é valida para o caso deste spider, visto que ele faz somente uma requisição (a primeira, feita para a URL em `start_urls`). Entretanto, é muito comum termos spiders que, após coletar os dados de uma página no método `parse()` (ou em outro callback), fazem novas requisições para URLs encontradas na própria página.

De qualquer modo, em projetos Scrapy é uma boa prática separar a lógica de validação e transformação de dados em **[Item Pipelines](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html)**.

Para isso, basta criar um pipeline como o do exemplo abaixo no arquivo `pipelines.py` dentro da pasta do seu projeto:

```
from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem


class DropDuplicatesPipeline(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.urls_seen = set()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        if item['link'] in self.urls_seen:
            raise DropItem('Duplicate item found: {}'.format(item['link']))
        else:
            self.urls_seen.add(item['link'])
            return item
```

E habilitá-lo no arquivo `settings.py` com o seguinte snippet:

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    'your_project.pipelines.DropDuplicatesPipeline': 300,
}
```

Feito isso, todo e qualquer item extraído pelo seu spider irá passar pelo método `process_item` acima, sendo rejeitado se já tiver sido extraído anteriormente.

Comment: show, muito obrigada

Comment: nele eu to conseguindo pegar o title e o url, se eu quisesse add o nome do produto como faria?